# ddply skip if nrow = 1

Tags: r, plyr, skip

I have a `ddply` that goes over a list of IPs and applies a fun over each IP. I want the fun to return a value only if the `nrow(ip.data) > 1`. Otherwise, I want `ddply` to skip over that IP and continue. How can I do this?

eg:

```
pd.outs <- ddply(server_ips, .(ip), function(x) get.ip.outs(x$ip, data))
```

`nrow(ip.data)` will provide the length of the number of rows in the subset of (data).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way is to just return `NULL` where `nrow(x)==1`:

```
pd.outs <- ddply(server_ips, .(ip), function(x) {
  if (nrow(x) == 1) {
    return(NULL)
  }
  get.ip.outs(x$ip, data)
})
```

Comment: Hi Peyton, thanks ! your suggestion worked. I added the return statement to my main fun and things are fine. THanks again.

Comment: Or just do `function(x) if (nrow(x) > 1) get.ip.outs(x$ip, data)`